# Detecting the background color of the option menu

Tags: android, options-menu

I have realized that there are at least two background colors on Option menu of Android. On the HTC Hero, the background is white and on Samsung Galaxy S II, the background is black.

This became a problem when I set the icons for the background menus. Is there some way to detect the background color of the Option menus in Android?

Comment: The difference is not between phones, but between Android versions. The background (and most of the "chrome" I guess) became black on Gingerbread (2.3). As long as you stick to the gray icon look, it should work in both versions (and future ones, presumably).

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions:

- Don't use icons.
- Design icons according to the guidelines - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html. There are three different guidelines for up to 2.2 (white background), 2.3 (black background) and 3.0+, so it's a lot of work...
- As Profete162 suggested, use @android:drawable/ic_menu_*

For Android 4.0+, you can also set the light / dark Holo theme, which is guaranteed (at least in theory) to remain unchanged across different phone manufacturers - so it'll look the same in HTC Sense, Samsung TouchWiz etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using @android:drawable/ic_menu_* now.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed a very annoying issue.

On my implementation, I always try to use standards icons from android.R.drawable.IC_menu_*****, so I am sure these icons are part of the framework and users are always positively surprised to see their generic icons in my app!

That gives a really good continuity in the user experience on the device, but that doesn't answer your question, but at least provide a workaround.

Here are for instance all android 2.2 icons: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/
You can trust me, using these icons will always fit your colors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know it. Here is some code if someone need it: <item 
     android:id="@+id/menuhelp"
     android:title="@string/menu_help"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />

Answer (score 1):

**First of all to answer your title question:**

You can reference and read the background of the options menu by reading the [attributes of the current theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes). The attribute for this is `panelFullBackground`. E.g. set it as the background of a textview in XML¹:

```
<TextView android:background="?android:attr/panelFullBackground" 
          ... />
```

Note that the background seems to be a solid color, but it's not - it's actually a bitmap. If you look closely you can see a grey border at the top *(android 2.3+)*, or a drop shadow (<= android 2.2), so its'a bit difficult. Luckily there is a different attribute called `panelColorBackground` which matches the background color of the drawable as close as possible. So if you want just the normal background color, use this instead.

¹ *This can surely also be read from code, but I don't know how from the top of my head at the moment, maybe I'll look it up and edit it in later.*

**Regarding icons**

So you have the color as stated above, but you still have to process it to know if it's a dark or a bright color. You can do that, but that's not the usual way to deal with these icons and probably a good bit of work until you cover all the possible cases - not to mention that you have to create icons for each variant.

Normally you should adopt the platform menu icon style. This works across all devices and looks familiar to your users *(custom icons that dont follow this often look "wrong" - e.g. astro file manager does this I believe)*.
You can do that by hand *(see the [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html))*, but the way better alternative is the Android Asset Studio.
It comes in two flavors:

- As a [webapp](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)
- Integrated in the latest version of the ADT plugin for eclipse
  *(under `File->New->Other->Android Icon Set`)*

The workflow for both is pretty similar, select the point "Menu Icon" and follow the wizard. It will promt you to enter a simple, black and white bitmap of your desired icon that just outlines it's shape. After you specified one, the asset studio will generate everything for you. Play a bit around with the "clipart" option, that has a few example bitmaps ready to see how it works. When finished, the webapp gives you a simple zip which can be extracted into your project directory, the eclipse version adds it directly to the project that you select in the wizard.

Comment: Whoa that got longer than expected. :o

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution definitively solve my problem. It seems that for develop an application, we need to know more than coding.

Answer (score -1):

The background color can be anything, because its implemented in Framework by manufacturer. You can't read it, in fact you will never need to read it.

Just create your custom menu layout in res/menu folder, set style and use it.

Comment: Well, sometimes I prefer to use my own buttons also.